# Microwave watt does it vary according to temp settings

Tags: equipment

I have an inverter of 600watt.  If I want to use a microwave of 700watt on the inverter and set the microwave temperature on medium and not high does the watt output of the microwave become less the lower the temperature?

Comment: Inverter fuse should burn out.

Comment: Microwaves usually change power levels by changing the percent of time that they are on at FULL power. Your 700 watt microwave likely draws 900 watts. The number on the box is tube output, and does not include fan, rotator motor or electronics.

Answer (score 2):

To your title, the answer is *maybe* (or yes if you average over a long enough time).

To the body of your question - the answer is *it probably won't work*.  Here's why: 
The microwave is meant to put out 700W.   It's not 100% efficient so will consume more than that (also for the light and turntable motor).

Most microwaves reduce their power by being fully on for a few seconds, off for a few seconds.  Some models have a type of inverter inside, and run at a lower continuous power but these tend to be higher-power models (mine, for example, is rated at 1000W).

Even then, your 600W inverter might be 600W peak or 600W continuous.  If it's rated to 600W continuous, it may be able to handle peaks of 700W+, but quite likely not for long.  It may also not be able to deliver its full rated power into a microwave - not all loads are created equal and the rating is probably for something simpler to drive such as a heater.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, inverter microwaves lower the power output depending on the setting so that there is continuous heating/cooking when switched on.

However, normal microwaves do not instead they cycle on and off to control the speed of heating. For example, at 100% it might be on throughout the cooking process, but at 50% it would be on for only 1/2 the time.